# Hi already running wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

> Warning:
>   require(/home/hitechinstitute/public_html/phonerepairingcourse/blog/wp-includes/load.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/hitechinstitute/public_html/phonerepairingcourse/blog/wp-settings.php
>   on line 23
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/hitechinstitute/public_html/phonerepairingcourse/blog/wp-includes/load.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/hitechinstitute/public_html/phonerepairingcourse/blog/wp-settings.php
>   on line 23

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the file load.php doesn't exist or having bad permissions :

```
/home/hitechinstitute/public_html/phonerepairingcourse/blog/wp-includes/load.php
```

first check if file exists, if yes try do change permission less restricted

hope it helps